# UICollectionView lags on scroll when im rendering Hindi font

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, fonts

I'm using a Hindi font in collection view cell, there are almost 15 cells loaded into collection view

on scroll it lags, when I use the English language it scrolls smooth, But when I change the language to Hindi it starts to lag on scroll

Is there any way to solve this issue? any font caching option for font?
Is there any way to improve this using CoreText rendering?

Comment: are you handling the text rendering in the form of an attributedstring in the cellForRow

Comment: Right now I'm doing that, I even tried as text but the same result. 
@Md.IbrahimHassan

Comment: scalling font is killing performance, make label bigger, or leave default hindi text and try if it is still lagging

Comment: I'm using font in UITextView, And I need to display large amount for text in Hindi @Lu_

Comment: so you will have lags

Comment: @Lu_ this is not small lag, It's huge lag, the scroll animation looks shit, Is there any way to improve its performance ?

Comment: try to do the processing part else where maybe in view did load or viewWillAppear and store the data in an array for use in the cellForRow

Comment: @Md.IbrahimHassan Can you give me an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the issue causing scroll lag:

The lag came because UITextView's scroll was disabled and on each scroll it had to calculate the height with rendering font.

I tried with fixed height for UITextView and scroll was enabled for the same the lag disappeared

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend reading [this](https://medium.com/capital-one-developers/smooth-scrolling-in-uitableview-and-uicollectionview-a012045d77f) article. It has a comprehensive set of scrolling optimisation practices for `UITableViews` and `UICollectionViews`

**UPD**

In your case I would look into `TextKit` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/CustomTextProcessing/CustomTextProcessing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH4-SW1):

> Text views, created from the UITextView class, are meant to display large amounts of text. Underlying UITextView is a powerful layout engine called Text Kit. If you need to customize the layout process or you need to intervene in that behavior, you can use Text Kit.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @inoky for me the font rendering is causing lag

Comment: @AlbinCR have you tried rendering the collectionView as image when scrolling?

Comment: @AlbinCR updated answer with `TextKit` link. I think this is where you can find an answer.

Comment: there is no images in the collectionView only text